# MySQL Database encoding

Tags: java, mysql, encoding

Before start, sorry for my English.

I have a problem with MySQL. I create database, and change encoding strings to latin2. Query from Java:

```
`INSERT INTO infos VALUES ( NULL, '100001486491198', 'ęłóżźćść!@#', '2013-12-23 11:24:37', 0, 0, 0 );`
```

In database all looks like "???????". I change this string to targen in phpMyAdmin, and when i execute SELECT query i get appropriate string in response.

Furthermore i add this code to database connection:

```
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put( "user", DBUSER );
      properties.put( "password", DBPASS );
      properties.put( "characterEncoding", "ISO-8859-2" );
      properties.put( "useUnicode", "true" );

    try {
        Class.forName( DBDRIVER ).newInstance();
        connection  = DriverManager.getConnection( DBURL, properties ); 
        statement   = connection.createStatement();
    } 
    catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but in response i get error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xB3\xF3\xBF\xBC\xE6\xBF...' for column 'content' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4190)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4122)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2812)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1811)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1725)
    at com.mpkinfo.server.database.Database.add(Database.java:48)
    ...
```

What i doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should choose utf8-bin, encoding for all your mysql tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if use unicode characters, set all tables and files encodings to utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise you to use UTF8, but if you insist on ISO-8859-2, you'll have to change your `DBURL` to looks like:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabase?useUnicode=falsee&characterEncoding=ISO-8859-2
```

Comment: i changed before, the same response. But UTF-8 helps. Thanks

Comment: if utf helps, use : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDatabase?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8

Comment: What is different beetween set properties in URL and use Properties class?